# podio .net The app with id XXXXXXXX does not have the right view on profile with id XXXXXXX

Tags: .net, api, podio

i'm trying to assign a contact to a new item that is being created.
but at item creation I get the error:

```
403
forbidden
The app with id 10923855 does not have the right view on profile with id 2609818
```

the code segment:

```
/* Text Field with external_id 'resposible' */
var _responsible = myNewItem.Field<ContactItemField>("responsible");
_responsible.ContactId = 2609818;
```

I've checked the app permissions and I cant see anything wrong.
any help will be greatly appreciated.
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you authenticate as an app you only have access to items in that specific app. You don't have access to all workspace contacts, only those created by the app or already in use in that app.

Comment: thanks for your response. I understand what you're saying, but the contact I'm trying to assign to is already member of the workspace. wouldn't the app have the permission to reference this member? I also tried to creating a contact and that didn't work either. I received the following error:
    400
    contact.space.user_not_allowed
    You cannot use Internal in this field as they are a space contact and you are using the contact field to share the item. Please remove them to continue.

I'm really just trying to allocate a member to the item being added. Have you any further suggestions?

Comment: Hi Andreas,
I figured it out. I was sending the user_id and not the profile_id.
thanks for your help.