# How can I get a task and update with API php?

Tags: php, api, podio

I'm using Podio API PHP to try to update some tasks, I'm using the method `PodioTask::get($task_id);` as the documentation says, but is not working, I'm receiving the following error message:

> The user with id 4654583 does not have the right view on task with id
> 355

This is the code

```
$task_id = 355;
$items = PodioTask::get($task_id);
dump_var($items);
```

Does anybody has the same issue?
In advance, thank you for your help

Comment: Do you have selected in your Modify App Settings > Advanced the box with "don't let members edit items in this app"?

Comment: Hi Tiago, I just review and the field you mentioned is not checked or selected

Comment: Can you try to authenticate before the get method? `Podio::authenticate_with_password( 'admin_user_email', 'password' );`

Comment: Also, [ensure the stored value remains int](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41043546/5675325)

Comment: Hi Tiango, yes I am authenticated, but I found the problem, there was another app called tasks and that was where I have to access, so I used PodioItem::get_basic(99999) and it works. Thaank you for you help anyway.

Comment: Cool, glad you've made it!